# ufw is enable but still be able to surfing web

Tags: firewall

I enabled ufw as a security practice. And let the default setting intact.
I noticed that I still be able to access internet using web browser, so I tested the firewall with transmission.
Transmission reported the port was closed. Then I allowed the port, and transmission reported it was opened.

This make me confused.
Why I still can surf the web when the default setting of firewall denies all incoming traffic of every port?
Are there other places for setting?

Thanks.

Comment: You initiate connection from your web browser and the firewall lets that "established" connection to come back to your PC. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

Comment: Yes, that is normal. Transmission does not initiate connection towards some other peer, it just listens for it so its port needs to be allowed in firewall. Set default-deny for outgoing and you'll block all traffic. It's a statefull firewall so it knows what state the connections are in. Based on that it filters them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall

Comment: UFW blocks incoming *connections* not incoming data. If you are running an apache server, you should not be able to access it on port 80 from another computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web browser initiate outgoing connection. Ufw by default is blocking incoming connection. If you want block all web browser traffic you could add this rule:

```
sudo ufw deny out http  
sudo ufw deny out https
```

Or you can change default policy to deny outgoing :

```
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
```

Now all your outgoing traffic will be blocked, until you allow something by the rule